# Actions and Links in Sentence-style Custom Labels?

Tags: visualforce, customlabel, translation-workbench

When building a multi-language portal in Visualforce, developers can use [custom labels](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en_US) and the [Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wbench.htm) to create a fully functional site that is easy for administrators to translate.

However, in situations where interactivity is desired in the form of a link or action that is part of a sentence, how should custom labels be implemented?

Take this sentence for example: "Please **sign in** to see offers just for you!" The bold "sign in" text should be a link that pops up a modal authentication prompt.

In discussion with colleagues, two options came up for this sample scenario:

- Use three custom labels, one for the leading text, another for the "sign in" text, and a third for the trailing text.
- Use a single custom label and [add HTML to the label text](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008pfiIAA) for interactivity.

Neither option seems particularly attractive. Three custom labels seems clunky and assumes that in all languages the same leading-clickable-trailing structure exists. HTML inside a label seems like it would complicate translation efforts and also prevent Visualforce actions from being used.

Are there any other options to consider?